# ClickOnce won't install .Net 4.5 after product.xml changed

Tags: c#, clickonce, .net-4.5

I want to add .Net 4.5 as prerequisite for my c# application which I plan to deploy with ClickOnce and I've been experimenting with "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" and "Download prerequisites from the component vendor's web site" options. I had trouble making first one to work and finally I used Bootstrapper Manifest Generator to get public key and replaced it in the Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX45\Product.xml.

Second option worked at the first but after I made changes it stopped working. Now when I select it I get "The following package files could not found error: " without any package specified.

This is from install log:

```
> The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = Intel {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.1 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.0.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD11D5.tmp\"
Error: The following package files could not be found:
```

Do you have ideas what should I look for? Is there a way to download and overwrite Packages folder?